# listview directory/filelist subcolumn items

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listview named filelist that consist of filename, date, and size.  I am able to fill filename from a given drive\path with the following code:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(str);
foreach (DirectoryInfo d in di.GetDirectories())
    filelist.Items.Add(d);

foreach (FileInfo f in di.GetFiles("*"))
    filelist.Items.Add(f);
```

This gives the directory names and filenames in the path in str, but how might
I fill in the subcolumns date and size and how might I mark directories in my filename list with something like [ ] pairs.  I tried building a string dirname; as dirname="["+d.name+"]" and then did a filelist.Item.Add(dirname); but it showed up as blank.  No idea how to load anything into the date subcolumn or the size subcolumn even though f does have that data.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You need to add a ListViewItem class to ListView, not a string. So like this:

```
var listViewItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem(new string[] { dirname }, -1);
filelist.Item.Add(listviewItem1);
```

If you want to add more columns, , add them to the string array like { dirname, f.name }

It's confusing because the .Add() method takes an object, so you would think a string would be the logical choice, but it needs the ListViewItem because there's a lot more junk it can display rather than just a string, like icons for instance.

Comment: I did this and I still got blank for the directory name:                                    string dirname = "[" + d.Name + "]";
var listViewItem1 = new  System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem(new string[] { dirname }, -1);
filelist.Items.Add(listViewItem1); and still got nothing but blank entries.

Comment: Try modifying the listview's Items collection directly. click on the listview control, then look in the properties window for Items. click the (...) and then hardcode in some entries and see if you can make that work. You might need to change the listview View to Details if you haven't yet. The point of hardcoding is to see if you've got some other problem displaying data in the listview. If you modify the Items collection using the GUI and still can't populate the listview, what I gave as an aswer isnt going to help.